# How do you make a single space between the first and second paragraph in an Android app description on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have tried both the new and old developer console using Chrome. If you enter a single blank line between the first and second paragraph in the "Description", the published app description appears without this space. Subsequent paragraphs appear fine. If you enter two spaces, there are two spaces in the published app description. Really Google?

I see it is possible since other apps have one space. There are also some that are apparently experiencing this same bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing a blank space character on the blank line will ensure the blank line shows up in the store.